# Conditional tags don't work

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I'm trying to display different templates in archive.php page. I need to load different article display depending on custom post type. Here is my code:

```
<?php if(is_singular('libri')) :?>

<?php 
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'libri',
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>


<?php endif; ?>


<?php get_footer();?>
```

Anyway the page doesn't display anything. 
How can I get rid of this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say the page doesn't display anything, do you mean it shows no posts, or do you mean you get a blank white screen with nothing at all? Have you checked your PHP error log and done the standard debugging checks?

Comment: It doesn't display anything but header and archive title. Can I debug with a plugin?

Comment: To start debugging I would put something in each "else" clause. Something like 'echo "No posts found in the loop."'; and then right before endif 'echo "Not singular libri."'; Then you will be able to tell which conditions are or aren't being met.

Comment: `is_singular` will return false on an archive page. If you wanted to check if you are on an archive for a post type, you would use `is_post_type_archive( 'libri' ) `, or you can create an `archive-{post_type}.php` file, which on this case would be `archive-libri.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_singular` will return false on an archive page. If you wanted to check if you are on an archive for a post type, you would use `is_post_type_archive( 'libri' )` , or you can create an `archive-{post_type}.php` file, which on this case would be `archive-libri.php`

References: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page

Answer (score 0):

You use [`is_singular()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular)  which is never going to return `true` on archive page, as [@Tom J Nowell](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) pointed out in the comment. So what you need to do for `query` to execute is to remove that condition.

Comment: I tried also without array but it doesn't work...

Comment: I've just edited as noticed sth intereseting.

Comment: `is_singular` ( aka is this page showing just a single post? ) refers to the current page, not the current post, so on an archive it will always be false, even inside a query/post loop. Unless you're doing queries with `query_posts`, which is bad practice